# How to echo all values from a specific array?

Tags: php

This is what I'm doing:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $max; $i++) {
    if(isset($media[$i])) {
        $combined[] = ["type" => "media", "value" => $media[$i]];
    }
    if(isset($content[$i])) {
        $combined[] = ["type" => "content", "value" => $content[$i]];
    }
    if(isset($yt[$i])) {
        $combined[] = ["type" => "youtube", "value" => $yt[$i]];
    } 
}

echo implode(', ', array_column($combined, 'media'));
```

Basically I need to echo all values of "media" as a single string with value separated commas.

Tried this too:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
  return $entry['media'];
}, $combined));
```

Comment: what about just `var_dump()`? Also I do not see any key `media` you refer to.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski i don't need a var_dump but to retrieve the values on an echo from here $combined[] = ["type" => "media", "value" => $media[$i]];

Comment: `media` is a value, not a key.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski how do i get all media?

Comment: by looping (i.e. `foreach`) and then checking **value** of `type`.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski ye but I don't want all echoed one by one, I need them all as a single string with separated commas

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I already do this when I need to foreach ($combined as $key => $val) { if($val['type'] == "media") {  but the question is different

Comment: @Sysix ye but that will give me all values for all types, I only need the media ones

Comment: then you should not use `array_map()` in first place, but i.e. `array_filter()` and then `array_map()`. But perhaps you should just whirl `foreach` as the logic can be more complex then and then rewrite if needed using `array_map()` and `array_filter()` once you know what you want to acheive

Comment: I dont' understand why don't you simply do ``$combined['media'][] = $media[$i]`` rather than making it complex.

Comment: @OMiShah what am I making complex?

Comment: @rob.m, By complex I meant to simply add all the ``media`` type values to the ``media`` key array so that you can have all the media under a single key ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = '';
foreach ( $combined as $com ) {
    if ( $com['type'] === 'media' ) {
        $string .= $com['value'] . ',';
    }
}
$string = rtrim( $string, ',');  // remove trailing comma
echo $string;
```

Comment: this is broken...

Comment: Yes, got the trim round the wrong way, fixed

Comment: please use `===`

Comment: ok, if you would like me to

Comment: it's not removing the la comma, result is 387,389, @RiggsFolly

Comment: also for removal trailing coma - it's more clearer if you would i.e. introduce `$sep` variable being empty and then assign `,` after first loop. Sure you will be reassigning in vain in the loop but the code will be clearer.

Comment: Woops me again, fixed `$string = rtrim( $string, ','); `

Comment: beautiful, works. Thank you

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Please explain why, in this situation, you think `===` is better than `==`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i was about to ask it too